# Prevent rsync from deleting destination files that match a given pattern

Tags: unix, rsync

I'm using rsync to sync files from a source to a destination:

```
rsync -av --delete source destination
```

I have a single directory on the destination side which is not on the source side. I'd like to prevent rsync from deleting this directory. Is there an option I can pass to rsync to prevent this directory from being deleted upon sync?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can exclude files/directories with --exclude.  This will prevent the somedir directory from being synced/deleted:

```
rsync -avrc --delete --exclude somedir source destination
```

Comment: If you want to exclude `somedir` from only one specific location in the directory tree you can anchor the exclude with a "/". This will improve performance - rsync will only have to check the path once! eg.
`rsync -avrc --delete --exclude /path/p2/somedir source destination`

Comment: `-r` is implied by `-a` and not required.

Comment: For anyone wondering what the `rc` are about in the above `-avrc`, they have nothing to do with this question. (r=recursive, c=skip based on checksum)

Answer (score 51):

As mentioned in a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/161766/how-to-exclude-rsync-excludes-from-delete), this can be accomplished by using the `--filter` option with `protect` rule:

```
$ rsync ... --filter 'protect /remote-directory-to-keep/' ...
```

Unlike the currently accepted answer, using `--filter` is useful, for instance, if you also wish to use `--exclude` with `--delete-excluded`.

Comment: this also works with `--filter 'protect *.js' --filter 'protect *.js.map'`