# How to enable two-way folder sync in Vagrant with VirtualBox?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I haven't used Vagrant on Linux for a while. When I started using the new version (Vagrant 1.8), I was faced with a problem: files created inside the guest VM didn't appear on the host machine's synced folder.

How do I force Vagrant to sync files from the guest OS to the host OS?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to documentation, when `type` option `config.vm.synced_folder` parameter in Vagrantfile is not specified, Vagrant tries to choose best available option:

> `type` (string) - The type of synced folder. If this is not specified, Vagrant will automatically choose the best synced folder option for your environment. Otherwise, you can specify a specific type such as "nfs".

Starting with version 1.5 Vagrant [introduced](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-5-rsync.html) new "rsync synced folders" feature.

So in my case type `rsync` was automatically chosen, which is one-way sync: from host to guest.

To make folders sync in two-way I added explicit definition in my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"
```

Of course, this will work only for VirtualBox.

Two way sync is useful for workflows, where apllication on guest machine creating files, for example, database migration files in modern web frameworks.

Note: virtualbox synced folders have known performance issues when your project has large amount of files.

Comment: After a fresh install, you are likely to receive the following error creating the shared folder:
```Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box.```
**Install Guest Additions**
```vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest```

Comment: @Alex: that didn't work for me. I get this: "Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'vagrant-hostmanager (= 1.8.6)'"

Comment: @AlexHendren In 2018, you can use vagrant-vbguest plugin which automatically installs the host’s VirtualBox Guest Additions on the guest system. Install it via `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`

Comment: in case it helps anyone, on my CentOS 7 vagrant box, I had to `vagrant ssh` into the box and run `sudo yum -y update` then close the ssh session and run a `vagrant reload` in order to sort out some kind of kernel header issue before this would work.  This wasn't an issue for me the last time I spun up a new vm (~middle of 2018) but now was required to get bidirectional synced directories to work with vagrant and centos7

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this it was exactly what I have looking for the past several days !!!!!   I had this problem with Laravel 5, homestead and vagrant.  Many answers out there but none that worked for me. I also had rsync in my folders section of my yaml file that I also had to remove.  After these two changes file sharing was finally sync for me between the host and client.

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')
```

**config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"**

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

Here is where I made the change to my Vagranfile.